# Receiving a pipe from Injector when only name is known

Tags: angular, typescript

I plan to have a service that can use pipes like templates. For this propose I need to get the registered pipes.

The code should look like this in the end:

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
    construct(private injector: Injector) {}

    // text could be something like 'myDate | date' or 'aVariable | uppercase'
    public interpolate(text: string, params: object = {}): string {
      let p: number = text.lastIndexOf('|');
      if (p > -1) {
        let args = [this.interpolate(text.substring(0, p))];
        let pipeName = text.substr(p+1).trim();
        // how ever we get the rest of the args from pipeName
        pipe = this.getPipe(pipeName)
        pipe.transform.apply(pipe, args);
      } else {
         // how ever we interpolate the base
      }
    }

    private pipeInstances: any = {}
    private getPipe(pipeName) {
      if (!this.pipeInstances[pipeName]) {
        // how to get the pipe?
        this.pipeInstances[pipeName] = this.injector.get(PipesContainer).get(pipeName);
      }

      return this.pipeInstances[pipeName];
    }
}
```

The problem is that you can't get pipes from injector. You have to provide them first (once for directives and once of providers). I'm looking for a way to get them from angular (compiler, core - what ever. somewhere have to be a list - may be for the root module) instead of defining a new list.

Comment: How do you call this?

Comment: from different places. from other services, from a pipe and from a component

Comment: what is the actual requirement?

Comment: I'm developing a module (angular-translator) and in the translations you can use parameters. and in language xx it might be necessary to use a pipe.

Answer (score 3):

There's no clean idiomatic way in Angular to get a pipe this way. Just because they are used internally by compiler and not exposed for injection. If pipes are supposed to be injected with injector, they should be defined as providers.

Since pipes are injectables, getting their instances with injector is the only proper way to do this. This can be implemented with a map of available pipes.

```
export const pipesMap = {
  some: SomePipe
}

export const pipesList = Object.values(pipesMap);

@Injectable();
export class Pipes {
  protected pipesMap = pipesMap;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  get(pipeName) {
    return this.injector.get(this.pipesMap[pipeName]);
  }
}

...
providers: [pipesList, Pipes, ...],
...
```

Filling the map can be automated by specifying an array of pipe classes and using [`PipeResolver`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/compiler/src/pipe_resolver.ts#L25) to get their names:

```
import {PipeResolver} from '@angular/compiler';

const pipeResolver = new PipeResolver();

export const pipesList = [
  SomePipe
];

export const pipesMap = pipesList.reduce((pipesMap, pipeClass) => {
  const pipeName = pipeResolver.resolve(pipeClass, true).name;
  pipesMap[pipeName] = pipeClass;
  return pipesMap;
}, {});

...
```

Since pipes are supposed to be instantiated by the compiler once per binding, `injector.get(...)` may not work for some pipes. `AsyncPipe` is illustrative in this case, [it is stateful and also uses `ChangeDetectorRef` dependency](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L70-L77), which isn't available for injection outside the compiler.

So in the end this should be solved on per pipe basis, depending on developer's needs and pipe's internals. Well-designed pipes are often thin wrappers for the relevant documented services, a good practice is to use these service directly if possible.

Comment: ok, that is the workaround I told about. thanks for this answer but it's not a solution. maybe it is really not possible without refactor something in angular itself. if this is the result I will open a feature request.

Comment: I believe this is the closest idiomatic solution you can get. It's not really bad to have WET code that enumerates the stuff explicitly, as long as it's clean, maintainable and testable, while its DRY counterpart isn't.

Comment: I guess it is possible to hack through the compiler to the list of pipes somehow, but this will result in relying on internal things (which is bad) and screwing up AoT beyond repair (which is really bad). Considering the direction that Angular chose, it is highly unlikely that something will change with a feature request. It should be noticed that this couldn't be done without hacking even in Angular 1, which was much more unrestrictive.

Comment: in angular1 you can inject `$filter` and use this... when there is no way to do it at all currently maybe a feature request will have it's reason.

Comment: I found another big problem with the injector: may be a specific pipe needs a new instance every time (like the `AsyncPipe` and yes my `TranslatePipe` too) but I don't know a way to do it with the hierarchical injection strategy.

Comment: Since in A2+ nothing is identified by string (unless you make it so), this is totally different case. Pipes don't need new instances, they are instantiated once per injector. E.g. AsyncPipe uses ChangeDetectorRef, which is not a normal provider. You will need to extend the class and likely provide some mocked CD implementation... not even sure how it is going to work and what's the purpose of doing that.

Comment: That's why you would never want to be able to use all the available pipes automagically - it just smells bad and results in unpredictable things, the list of available pipes should be manually curated. When you need some functionality that a pipe offers, you use the services a pipe uses instead. If the functionality is not available as a service, you create an mix-in class that wraps pipe's `transform` method. It depends on what you exactly need, but usually it's that simple.

Comment: I don't know why you think it is a single instance. I know it's not. See  https://github.com/tflori/angular-translator/blob/master/src/TranslatePipe.ts

Comment: Because Angular injectables are singletons (within a single injector), and pipe class is instantiated once per component). Yes, this is an example of a 'good' pipe, this was my point. It is a thin wrapper around other services, it makes more sense to use the services directly instead of hacking around the pipe (which wasn't developed to be used directly outside of component views any way). There are also 'bad' pipes (e.g. Angular built-ins) where calling `transform` directly is the only way to use their functionality.

Comment: I just tried again: pure pipes are single instances impure pipes not - what makes sense. The use case for accessing pipes by name is up to the developer. But to discuss it here and on github makes no sense.

Comment: You're right about impures. And among those only AsyncPipe looks like it is stateful and needs to be re-instantiated - and the one would have a hard time making it work properly outside of the template. Feel free to ask a question if you will have problems with some particular pipe. It's not easy to come up with universal $filter replacement but it may be easy to solve a specific problem.